# Excel If-Else formula to capture ''hour" and "min" across an excel row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a row of "h min" values (eg:2h 15min) across a row. I need to capture the 'hour' and 'min' separately for which I'm using "=LEFT(B2,(FIND(" ",B2,1)-1))" and "=MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,256)" in separate cells, using the space separator to identify them seperately.

The problem is when there is only either one value, i.e. only hour or only minute (eg. "2h" or "20min") in which case I get an error. How should I re-code both my LEFT and MID formula to ensure it still captures the hour/minute where it's present and gives a blank where it's not present.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day Mithun, Maybe these might help.

Hour Formula - =IFERROR(LEFT(B2,(FIND("h",B2)-1)),0)
Minute Formula - =IFERROR(MID(B2,FIND("min",B2)-2,2),0)

As the screen cap shows if the there is not a space between the two figures the minute formula fails.

[image]

If you want to add the text afterwards add a custom format link ##" h", and ##" min"

I hope this helps,
Brad